# Bash route a SIGINT to a file/process started from Bash script

Tags: javascript, bash, sigint

I have a bash script (startup.sh) that executes a NodeJS file, and this javascript file listens for a SIGINT signal. I am running into the problem that, when I run the whole setup via startup.sh and then use Control + C, this seems to kill the bash script before the javascript file ever receives the signal.

Is there any way I can prevent startup.sh from terminating on SIGINT signal, and instead route that to the javascript file? I have been trying some solutions using trap and kill but I have not gotten very far. Thank you!

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
node myFile.js
```

myFile.js

```
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
   console.log("Cleaning up")
   // Do some cleanup work
})
```

To specify, with the current state of everything, if I run  `node myFile.js` and send a SIGINT, everything works fine. However, if I run `startup.sh` and then send a SIGINT signal, I don't see "Cleaning up" which I am presuming because SIGINT shuts down the startup.sh process and so myFile.js never receives this signal.

Comment: Use `exec` so that the node process replaces the script process, instead of spawning it as a child. The other route would be to include a `trap` in the bash script.

Comment: I am not sure if exec will work in the real context. Would I use trap to ignore the signal? Something like trap - SIGINT is what I have been trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is just this one-liner, `exec` will do. You might also just use an `alias`, if that is feasible.

If your start-up script will eventually become a larger script, you might just trap the sigint, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
tokill=$$

function no_ctrlc()
{
    echo "Killed the nodejs"
    kill -3 $tokill
    exit
}

trap no_ctrlc SIGINT


node myFile.js &
tokill=$!
wait
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! If I wanted to wait on the node program, I would replace the exit with a wait inside of no_ctrlc?

Comment: No, you should put a `wait` before the `exit`. That makes it easier to understand what is happening. It will work tough if you put a wait instead of the exit.